# Need some hints to solve a problem from "Revue de la filière mathématique"

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

Let $A\in M_{n}(\Bbb R)$ and $B\in M_{n,m}(\Bbb R)$ and $C=\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(sA\right)BB^T\exp\left(sA^T\right)\,{\rm d}s$.

Prove that $C$ is invertible if and only if
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} Im(A^iB)=\Bbb R^n$

I found this weird-looking challenging problem in "Revue de la filière mathématique". I have tried to solve it in specific cases such as $m=1$ or $n=1$ but can't find the way for the general case. It's really mysterious and surprising to me how the integral, the exponential function and the properties of linear operators can have a beautiful relationship between them.

I've get stuck on the problem for days and I need some hints :)
(Here we regard a matrix $M\in M_{n,m}(\Bbb R)$ as a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$)

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Could you provide your tries for $m=1$ or $n=1$, so people have something to start with and give you better hints.

Comment: The case n=1 is trivial but the case m=1 is so much harder that I've not solved it yet.

Comment: Do you mean that the case $n=1$, $m$ arbitrary is trivial, while the case $n$ arbitrary, $m=1$ is complicated?

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean